# Buttonless Temperature Converter in Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub FahrenheitTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FahrenheitTextBox.TextChanged
    CelsiusTextBox.Text = 5 / 9 * (Val(FahrenheitTextBox.Text) - 32)
  End Sub

  Private Sub CelsiusTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CelsiusTextBox.TextChanged
    FahrenheitTextBox.Text = (9 / 5) * Val(CelsiusTextBox.Text) + 32

  End Sub
  End Class
```

---

So, that's my code. Our assignment was to create a temperature converter that worked without buttons- so, when I typed in the Fahrenheit box, it would automatically convert to Celsius in the Celsius box. The way I determined doing this was by using an if statement- my professor said I was not allowed to do that because we have not learned it yet. My problem right now is that the two TextChanged events are competing with each other- so when I type in one, it calculates the other, and then calculates the other and keeps going and messing up the numbers. I am not allowed to use an 'if statement'. His reply to my question if we could use an if statement was "*Adding IF statement would solve the problem together with TextChanged event. However, at this moment, let’s assume that we do not know IF statement (with Boolean values). In addition, it does not have to be complicated if you choose the right event for textbox.*" So...I don't really know how to proceed without an if statement or an event that would require pressing a key. I emailed him with my problems (stating I did not know how to proceed without the if statement or pressing a button (which would take away the automatic conversion)) He also stated, when I inquired about a KeyPress event, "*You are so close to the answer. KeyPress event asks you to press and hold the key before it works. How about other key events? I am sure you will get the solution out soon.*"

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: you can do this in many ways e.g. when input field loses focus you could calculate the temperature or do you need to do at each keypress? either way you need an event handler

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried KeyDown event? Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2